# JQGrid not reaching MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Using FireBug I know the url is 
http://localhost:21962/Home/DynamicGridData/?nd=1250169669898&_search=false&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Id&sord=desc

It is not making it to my HomeController.
Here are the actions I have tried to make receive the JQGrid call

public ActionResult DynamicGridData(long nd, bool search, int rows, int page, string sidx, string sord)

public ActionResult DynamicGridData(int page, int rows, string search, string sidx, string sord)

public ActionResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)

Comment: What does Firebug say the response from the server is?

Comment: Craig you rock.    I was confused by your question so Looked at firebug some more.   Found the response tab and it told me that it was confused as to which function to call.   I commented out to just one function and it works like a charm.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use firebug response tab to examine the response... per above comment
Cal-